# IntelliJ scala worksheet: Reduce debug logging

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

When using the worksheet with Slick, it logs so much debug that I don't see the actual result of what I'm doing. I've been trying to figure out how to disable the debug-logging for hours now, but I can't figure it out.

How do I disable the (slick)/(worksheet) logging?

from the worksheet:

```
  db.run(
    countries.take(5)
      .map(_.country)
      .result
  )
```

Which outputs ~200 lines of:

```
countries: slick.lifted.TableQuery[Country] = Rep(TableExpansion)
z: slick.lifted.Query[Country,Country#TableElementType,Seq] = Rep(Filter @968224334)
res0: java.sql.Connection = org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@40d24bbd
BEFORE
22:17:58.192 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - Source:
| Bind
|   from s2: Take
|     from: TableExpansion
|       table s3: Table country
|       columns: ProductNode
|         1: Path s3.id : String'
|         2: Path s3.name : String'
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false)
|   select: Pure t4
|     value: Path s2.name : String'

22:17:58.193 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.AssignUniqueSymbols - Detected features: UsedFeatures(false,false,false,false)
22:17:58.194 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase assignUniqueSymbols:
| Bind
|   from s5: Take
|     from: TableExpansion
|       table s6: Table country
|       columns: ProductNode
|         1: Path s6.id : String'
|         2: Path s6.name : String'
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false)
|   select: Pure t8
|     value: Path s5.name : String'

22:17:58.195 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase inferTypes: (no change)
22:17:58.196 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.ExpandTables - Found Selects for NominalTypes: @t7
22:17:58.197 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.ExpandTables - With correct table types:
| Bind : Vector[t8<String'>]
|   from s5: Take : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     from: Table country : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false) : Long
|   select: Pure t8 : Vector[t8<String'>]
|     value: Path s5.name : String'

22:17:58.197 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.ExpandTables - Table expansions: @t7 -> (s6,ProductNode)
22:17:58.198 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase expandTables:
| Bind : Vector[t8<String'>]
|   from s5: Take : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     from: Table country : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false) : Long
|   select: Pure t8 : Vector[t8<String'>]
|     value: Path s5.name : String'

22:17:58.199 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase forceOuterBinds:
| Bind : Vector[t8<String'>]
|   from s5: Take : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     from: Table country : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false) : Long
|   select: Pure t8 : Vector[t8<String'>]
|     value: Path s5.name : String'

22:17:58.200 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase removeMappedTypes: (no change)
22:17:58.200 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase expandSums: (no change)
22:17:58.201 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase expandRecords:
| Bind : Vector[t8<String'>]
|   from s5: Take : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     from: Table country : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false) : Long
|   select: Pure t8 : Vector[t8<String'>]
|     value: Path s5.name : String'

22:17:58.202 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Flattening projection t8
22:17:58.202 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Analyzing s5.name with symbols 
| Path s5.name : String'

22:17:58.203 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Translated s5.name to:
| Path s5.name

22:17:58.203 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Flattening node at Path 
| Path s5.name

22:17:58.204 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Adding definition: s9 -> Path s5.name
22:17:58.204 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Adding translation for t8: (Map(List() -> s9), UnassignedType)
22:17:58.204 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.FlattenProjections - Flattened projection to
| Pure t8
|   value: StructNode
|     s9: Path s5.name

22:17:58.205 [NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile-server] DEBUG slick.compiler.QueryCompiler - After phase flattenProjections:
| Bind : Vector[t8<{s9: String'}>]
|   from s5: Take : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     from: Table country : Vector[@t7<{id: String', name: String'}>]
|     count: LiteralNode 5 (volatileHint=false) : Long
|   select: Pure t8 : Vector[t8<{s9: String'}>]
|     value: StructNode : {s9: String'}
|       s9: Path s5.name : String'
```

(and it goes on and on and on...)

So how do I turn off this logging?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the default [sbt directory structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html), you need to [configure logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) to log only what you want. To do so, add a file `src/main/resources/logback.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="slick.lifted" level="INFO" />

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Of course, you can configure other log level besides `INFO` and also other log levels for specific slick packages.

And finally, if you are using Playframework directory structure, put the `logback.xml` file inside `conf` directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Scala worksheet with Spark code where it wrote literally hundreds of `DEBUG` messages to the log - all starting with `[NGSession 241: 127.0.0.1: compile] DEBUG ...`

The project uses several modules and no matter where I put the adjusted `logback.xml` file, it didn't get picked up.

I noticed that this `NGSession` relates to the Scala compile server. By specifically telling the server which `logback.xml` to use, it was picked up:

[image: Open compile server configuration]

Add the parameter...

[image: Parameter added to compile server configuration]

After that I restarted the compile server (Stop/Start) and it worked.